# How to get a truly blank vanilla app with eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I have made several apps before using eclipse. I (think) always started out with file>new>project>application project and eclipse set up a project in which the main activity was comprised of a black screen with nothing in it - until I used the "graphical layout" editor to start adding some buttons/text etc.

But in more recent versions of eclipse it appears that however hard I try, I always seem to ens up with some components already on my activities screen. It appears that some "style" or "theme" (whatever they are) has been selected in the process and my activity starts with a fat bar across the top with my application's icon on the left of it. I have attempted to make edits to various xml files to remove the unwanted icon/bar, but so far to no avail.

What do I need to do to get a properly blank application so that I can be fully in charge of every pixel on the screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your graphical layout preview select AppTheme select theme select Theme.NoTitleBar.FullScreen

You should see a preview with no title bar

[image]

Add this in manifest for your activity

```
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
```